# Is there a way to define a function of a meniscus curvate?

Tags: optics, surface-tension

If you cut a thin slit in thin  opaque material and then put it into water and pull it out, the meniscus will be formed in the slit. For my research I need to know if it is analytically possible to define the curvature of meniscus( is it hyperbola, parabola, circle or something else).

I need the function of curvature so I will be able to make calculations of how the light passes through the meniscus.
I know there are numerical methods to make an approximate function, but I want to know if there is any other way.

Comment: I don't know if it's the right way to approach this, but I think the problem resembles that of the catenary (hanging rope): upward tension forces on the sides (here because of adhesion), and downward forces in between (because of gravity and cohesion). 

In that way you can approach it's form as a hyperbolic cosine in the cross-section (potentially rotated around it's symmetry axis if you use a cylindrical tube). I don't think it's the exact equation here, but I think it's a pretty good approximation.

Comment: I gave a derivation of the shape of a meniscus for a circular container at http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/156091/26969 - it should be easy to adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are referring to a problem in the [calculus of variations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) known as [Plateau's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau%27s_problem).

This involves solutions of boundary value problems for the Laplace equation that satisfy the Dirichlet principle, and for simple boundary conditions you should be able to find analytic solutions in the literature.