# Why is the liquid surface concave when it wets a container?

Tags: surface-tension, wetting

[image]

As you can see in this diagram the surface of the liquid is concave, why is the part of the liquid surface adjacent to the container has higher height than the rest of the surface, is it because it's not surrounded from all directions by molecules of the liquid so the cohesive force is smaller than the liquid in the middle which is surrounded with liquid molecules from multiple directions?

Comment: this is "capillary action", if you search for it on the internet, you would find a lot of info

Comment: That is Called lower Meniscus

Comment: This doesn't always happen. Mercury for example shows the opposite effect, the meniscus is convex. Sadly I don't remember how this works but it should be the combination of at least 2 effects.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/156076/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

The curvature of the surface happens due to the adhesional forces between glas and water. Those are higher than the cohesional forces inside the water. An indicator for this is the wettability.
The phenomenon depends on the texture of the surface and the surface tension of the liquid.

Comment: But the opposite phenomenon can also occur: when the adhesional forces between material 1 and material 2 is *lower* than the cohesional forces between material 1 and material 2.